# Why does Visual Studio think I'm on a different branch than my terminal and VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have a .NET 5 solution, using git for source control.

- If I open it in Visual Studio 2019, the branch selector at the bottom right says `foo`
- If I navigate to the root directory in a terminal window and check the current branch with `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`, it says I'm on branch `bar`
- If I open the root directory in VS Code, it also says I'm on branch `bar`
- If I checkout another branch from my terminal like this: `git checkout main`, then both my terminal and VS Code say that my current branch is `main`, but VS2019 still says `foo`

What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure *why* this was happening, but deleting the `.vs` folder and restarting the solution/VS2019 seems to have fixed it.

```
Root Directory
- .git
- .gitignore
- README.md
- src
  + .vs    // deleted this and restarted VS2019
  + MySolution.sln
```